# My layout view won't recognize my BaseModel object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I followed the instructions in [this blog post](http://dtoncode.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/strongly-typed-models-on-your-layout/) to create a strongly-typed view model for my _layout.cshtml file because I hate using ViewBag. Here is my base controller that all my other controllers inherit from:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected BaseViewModel ModelBase { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var contextItems = filterContext.HttpContext.Items;
        if (contextItems["ModelBase"] == null)
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ModelBase"] = this.ModelBase;

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        this.ModelBase = new BaseViewModel
        {
            Theme = Request.QueryString["theme"] ?? "cyborg"
        };
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

All I'm trying to do is grab a query string variable called "theme" and add it's value to the Theme property on `BaseViewModel`. According to the blog post I should be able to do `@ModelBase.Theme` in the layout view but I get no intellisense and it throws an error when I run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a custom razor view base class as described in Phil Haack's post here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@model BaseViewModel` to strongly type your model in the view. Then you can use  `@Model.Theme`

Comment: All that does is type the view to `BaseViewModel`. The model isn't actually being populated. Remember, this is a layout view.